# Learning traditional Chinese characters

Tags: traditional-characters, resources, learning

I am keen to learn more on traditional Cchinese characters for reading and writing.

Which site should I go to for basic learning?

Comment: I am only English Language user. I was told to learn Traditional Chinese which is often used in HK so that I can able to learn HK sign language. 
I am totally noob to this Chinese language. Sorry for my question which is voted for "on hold".

Comment: In this case, why not read something on Wikipedia first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Written_Chinese On Quora you will find tons of questions with good answers about how to get started with Chinese. On Chinese StackExchange, questions focused on details, grammar, expressions, usage, etc. are preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood you correctly and that by traditional Chinese you meant classical Chinese, or 文言文.

Assuming you have pretty decent knowledge in modern Chinese, you can start, like all Chinese students do nowadays and ancient elites likewise, from recitation and memorization of classical works. [古文观止](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh/%E5%8F%A4%E6%96%87%E8%A7%80%E6%AD%A2), literally meaning "stop reading any more classical works after this collection", is a selection, sorted chronologically roughly by dynasty, first published some hundred/two hundred years ago. I suggest you start with essays written in relatively more modern eras.

Good luck and have fun.
ps: there are of course some countably many (not in the mathematical sense) old syntactic as well as morphological (e.g. character "overloading", 通假字) rules that one should always know and that we were also taught after primary school, but I can't help you there because to me, these rules have already become innate and can't be enumerated without omission. But I do know that some Jesuits pastors who visited Chinese back in Ming dynasty have left some valuable notes, many of which titled as something similar to grammaticae sinicae. They were on google books some years ago, not sure if they still are.

Comment: I believe the traditional Chinese mentioned by OP is the non-simplified chinese

Comment: @Alex oh well, given that even the writing systems used in Hong Kong and Taiwan differ slightly, I would rather not make any remarks on that one. In any case, I guess a writing system can hardly be called as a language

Comment: agree on your point, however judging from OP's question style, it's unlikely that he's looking for classical Chinese / 文言文